# Accesing remote server get data and put it in hdfs

Tags: hadoop

floks

Here i have a client question. I want to get the tables from sql server(RDBMS) to my hdfs (hadoop cluster). But the servers are in different location.

1)Which is the best way to access the serve,but data is in huge amount.

2)connecting with one sever is okay, we have many servers around the globe we have to get the data from this servers.

3)Can we connect with sqoop remotly to get the data to HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit unclear, but yes, you can use sqoop to import the data from your servers into HDFS. You need to specify the connection parameters when importing the data:

```
sqoop import --connect <JDBC connection string> --table <tablename> --username <username> --password <password>
```

If you need to do multiple imports from multiple servers, I suggest you try Oozie to automate these imports. You can find a tutorial to achieve that [here](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html).

Comment: Actually my server is in different location, i have to access that server through internet. So there is huge amount of data in client system. How to get remotly located server data to hdfs with out any lose of data.

Comment: Ok, you mean that you need to move data from a server in a different location, to the HDFS in your cluster, right? Then where is the problem with the sqoop import command?

Comment: sqoop is used to get data from physically located server only, i think

Comment: That is not true. In the command you just change `--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1`, instead of `localhost` you write the IP of the server, and instead of `mysql` you put the port number.

Comment: Ip address may change dynamically,We have to get rdbms tables, there are around 600 tables , At time of importing  huge data if its disconnected due to low internet speed at client place.

Comment: This are all client questions come across,Thanks for your responce

Comment: Sqoop:how much time it will take to dump data to hdfs,Data is like 10TB

Comment: That will depend on many factors... The size of the cluster, the bandwidth, the specifications of the nodes in the cluster...

Answer (score 0):

Before writing down the sqoop import, you need to have a user for each of the remote node which is to be identified by your local DB. For Ex:

```
create user 'username'@'<ip of remote node>' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

You must also have to ensure about the grant permissions to these users depending on your requirement.
It's then you can frame the sqoop import, one example as below:

```
$SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop  import  --connect jdbc:mysql://<ip address of remote server node> :port_number/<database_name>  --username user  --password password  --table <table to import>
```

This question is 5 months old for this answer so I'm hoping the issue would have been resolved but in case someone wanted to go to a step by step procedure for this requirement.

Regards,
Adil